# How to display a Superscript in C# Dropdownlist, using html tags

Tags: c#, html, drop-down-menu

Hope someone can tell me how I should get a Superscript tag like ² to display correctly in the text of a Dropdownlist option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably using HTML entities:

```
&sup2;
```

instead of the actual character. But it's probably better to let C# take care of it:

```
string safeString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("your string²");
// Use the result as the displayed value in your Dropdownlist
```

This method will also find other problematic characters such as & and replace them accordingly. See [MSDN HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) for more information on this.

**Edit**: be advised; the resulting string from HtmlEncode will show (when used in HTML) exactly that what you have input in the method. So do not use HTML entities in your input, because then that's exactly what you'll see in the resulting page.

If you want to show m² then just enter that inside the method. .NET will take care of the rest.

Comment: Tried this, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("m&sup2;") gives me m&amp;sup2; in the Dropdownlist option

Comment: Yes that's logical! You should use the actual text you want to display. So if you want to show "m²", then use exactly that as your input.

Comment: That did it. Sometimes just do exactly what you want it to do instead of making it more complicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe unicode symbols would do the trick for you: http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/mathchart.html#super

For the superscripted two you would use `&#178;` resulting in: ²

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems to just print out &#178; in the option.

Comment: Then it is already html-encoding it for you, resulting in the `&` being converted to `&amp;` in the result and thus displaying it as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this way,

```
string item=HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("ml/min/1.73m&amp;#178;")
```

for more info on superscript you can see this link
http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html#super